# What REST method should I use when deleting a resource after reading it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest

For a project I'm working on, I have to long poll an endpoint to request a list of events. So, I'm running a locally hosted NodeJS server with an endpoint that returns the list of events that have come in since the last time the endpoint was hit. This endpoint clears the list every time it is read.

```js
const config = require('./config.json')
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

var events = [];

// fetch the list of events from the last read
app.get("/changes", function(request, response, next){
    response.json(events);

    // clear out the message queue
    events = [];
});

// other logic exists that adds events to the array

module.exports = {
    startAppServer : ()=> {
        const port = config.PUBLIC_PORT // 3000
        app.listen(port, function(){
            console.log(`${new Date()} - server is listening on port ${port}`);
        });
    },
}
```

I'm new to designing REST APIs, and this seems to be doing two operations of reading and deleting the resource. So my question is simply, should this be a GET because it is fetching the list of changes? or should it be a DELETE that returns the deleted elements?

Is there a cleaner, better, or more RESTful way to structure this? Separating the logic into two operations seems like an unnecessary call, even though traffic is not really a big concern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm new to designing REST APIs, and this seems to be doing two operations of reading and deleting the resource.

Yeah, that's kind of an unfortunate choice of implementation.

Good news: servers own the representations of their resources, and are allowed to change those representations any time they choose.  So creating a GET handler that erases data is permitted.

Bad news: when you do that, you introduce a bunch of failure modes that lose data.  If that loss of data is expensive (for whatever reason), then it's the fault of the server implementation.  See [Fielding, 2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html).

Here are two examples of failure modes you might care about.

1. HTTP messages often cross unreliable networks.  There are no guarantees that a message produced by the server will reach the client in a reasonable amount of time.  A repeated request will receive the empty list, and the original is gone.
2. HTTP semantics require that GET have [essentially read only](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-safe-methods) semantics, and *general purpose* HTTP components are allowed to leverage that.  That includes actions like prefetching a representation before the operator has asked for it.

If you have enough of the right countermeasures in place, you may be able to "get away with" using GET -- but if you are asking the question, you probably don't, so you shouldn't.

---

DELETE is not an acceptable option, because [RFC 9110 DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-delete) doesn't mean what you want it to mean.

Consider:

> Relatively few resources allow the DELETE method -- its primary use is for remote authoring environments, where the user has some direction regarding its effect.

---

[What you probably want here is POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post), with a payload that tells the server what the last known event was (by value or by Id), allowing the server to garbage collect those events where the delivery has been confirmed.

This is exactly what you would do if you were limiting yourself to out of the box HTML.  The representation of the resource would look like a list of events with a "mark-as-read" form at the bottom; the metadata necessary to identify which events had been read would be encoded into the representation of the form itself (perhaps as hidden inputs).

Comment: Thanks for the write up, references, and suggestions. The "mark as read" approach makes a lot of sense and would be fairly trivial to implement.